# How to store temporary CSV/XLSX files in kubernetes pod without using Volume/GCS?

Tags: scala, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-storage

I'm working on creating new UI to an existing application. It transforms XLSX to csv and writes data to DB. Most of the plugins uses Files read and write operation. Files may be as big as 1 or 2 GBs. Everything is good till we decided to move application to Kubernetes.

Problem:

1. Deployment team doesn't allow to use volumes in kubernetes
2. As old code uses file storage in many places, dependency to store files is very high. can't rewrite the code to do everything in-memory
3. Using google cloud storage, to download and convert blob and process it, stuck with same issue.
4. If we use container/pod's writable layer, if pod changes the vm during execution, we may lose the data and end up in error.

Solutions in list:

1. Docker TMPFS - not sure how supportive is Kubernetes
2. Use secret storage in Kubernetes - Yet to try

Need the best way out to manage a temporary location to manage files when the process is running. It is okay to delete the existing files after the process or once the container is destroyed as everything will be backed up in GCS.

Technologies: Spring boot, scala to process, Java to upload files

Comment: Any specific reason for the deployment team not allowing volumes in Kubernetes?

Comment: @AzizAlfoudari Because of security. A single volume can be shared among multiple pods. Anyone with internal GCP access can get to see shared data.

Comment: I would recommend the second solution, using a secret to store the file; however, keep in mind that if/when the pod gets killed, the file(s) will also be lost as well.

Comment: @Jason Thanks for suggestion. Decided to move on with regular VM than Kubernetes for now. Later got to work on solution to avoid using files and directly stream from GCS bucket.